# android quiz buttons are changing size and position, how to fix that

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm making a quiz in android, all done just need to make the layout look clean. The quiz layout has a question and 4 answer choices, everything is vertically and looks like a classic quiz app.

The thing is, with each question, the layout changes, buttons jump up and down and change size (height) depending on how many lines of text they have (some questions and answers have 2-3 lines). I want all elements to remain the same height and position no matter of the quantity of text, but failed no matter what I tried.

I always check multiple sources but decided to write a question. Can someone help, here is the .xml . The code is now a mess, it went through bunch of experimentation, sorry.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="hr.prepoznajmoenasilje.Kviz">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pitanje"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/o1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/o2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/o3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/o4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how I imagine it. I manage to make it look that way, but not without problems of height changing and positions moving.
[Preferred layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gbXs.png)

Comment: Well, how do you plan to handle viewing very large texts? For example 3 - 4 lines? You wanna scroll through the textview?

Comment: @Azhar92 Well the questions mostly have larger texts because their font size is bigger, but buttons have mostly 1-2, but when they have 2 they already mess up the positioning and height. I'd prefer to make the default height of the buttons and question textview big enough so that no matter how much text there is, everything would fit in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just made the height of textview a constant height instead of wrap content, thus disabling it to move around. Knew it was something silly but couldn't figure it out, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

**You need to set button height 0dp and also fix the textView size, Try this...**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_anim"
    tools:context="hr.prepoznajmoenasilje.Kviz">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pitanje"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/o1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/o2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/o3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/o4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```